# Make git ask Kleopatra to unlock GPG key for specific e-mail address

Tags: git, gnupg, openpgp, gpg4win

I'm on a Windows 10 machine with Gpg4win and Kleopatra installed, as well as the most recent version of git. In Kleopatra I have two OpenPGP certificates loaded, let's say for these e-mails:

- `john.doe@example.com` with Key-ID `AAABBBCC`
- `johnny@example.org` with Key-ID `FFF00011`

I have a *global* git config with these settings:

- `commit.gpgsign=true`
- `user.email=john.doe@example.com`

But I have a *repository* git config with a different, more specific email setting:

- `user.email=johnny@example.org`

But when I try to commit something in that repository I get a *pinentry-qt* popup with this message:

> Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:
>   "John Doe " 4096-bit RSA key, ID 88888888AAABBBCC, created 2018-04-10.

Is there any way to make git ask for the certificate specific to the e-mail I used? Failing that, is there perhaps a way to configure the ID of gpgsign per repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I found several GPG-related [`git config` options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), including one to do exactly what I want:

```
git config user.signingKey FFF00011
```

Note that this configures a parameter that will be passed to the GPG program (Kleopatra, in this case) which gets picked up correctly if you use the `Key-ID` that Kleopatra shows you for the certificate you want to use.